# Generalizing $\frac{1}{1+a^2}+\frac{1}{1+b^2} \le \frac{2}{1+ab}$ for $a+b \leq 2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

Let $ a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ $(n\ge 2)$ are positive reals such that $ a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\leq n.$ Prove that
$$\frac{1}{1+a^2_1}+\frac{1}{1+a^2_2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{1+a^2_n}\le \frac{n}{1+a_1a_2\cdots a_n}.$$

One can easily prove it for $n=2$ with simplifying. How would one generalize this ?

Comment: Have you tried induction ?

Comment: @EDX induction condition $\sum a_i\le n$ is not easy to propagate, so I doubt it can be done this way. I have also searched approach0, I saw many references to the problem in aops, but found no solution.

Comment: Why do you call that "generalization"? The inequality in the title is valid without the assumption $a+b\le2.$

Comment: @Professor Vector ..I think that condition is necessary for it rearranges to $(1-ab)(a-b)^2\geq 0$

Comment: So you need only the weaker condition $ab\le1$, right?

Comment: Well yeah, for this case... Not sure for the general one.

Comment: I guess a useful substitution would be $b_i= 1/a_i$ but I couldn't continue from there. I tried using $QM \ge AM$ but it didn't help much.

Comment: I have a proof when one of the variables is equal to zero do you want to see it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > lemma : The following function is concave on $]0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ :$$f(x)=\cos^2(x)=\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$

It's not hard to show using the second derivative or the definition of the convexity .Omitted.

Now we apply the Jensen's inequality to the function $f(x)$ we get for $0\leq a_i\leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ ($n$ real numbers) :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+\tan^2(a_i)}\leq \frac{n}{1+\tan^2\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)}$$

To prove your inequality we have to show :

$$\frac{n}{1+\tan^2\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)}\leq \frac{n}{1+\prod_{i=1}^{n}\tan(a_i)}$$

Or :

$$\tan^2\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)\geq \prod_{i=1}^{n}\tan(a_i)$$

But again with Jensen's inequality apply to $g(x)=\ln(\tan(x))$ wich is concave on $]0,\frac{\pi}{4}]$ we get :

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(\tan(a_i))\leq n\ln\Big(\tan\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)\Big)$$

Or :

$$\tan^n\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)\geq \prod_{i=1}^{n}\tan(a_i)$$

But $a_i\leq \frac{\pi}{4}$ so :

$$\tan^n\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)\leq \tan^2\Big(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i}{n}\Big)$$

So we showed the following theorem :

> > Let $0<x_i\leq 1$ be $n$ real numbers then we have : 
> >     $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{1+x_i^2}\leq \frac{n}{1+\prod_{i=1}^{n}x_i}$$

Maybe it can give idea to others...